# What's the equivalent of InvokeUnmarshalled from JS to .Net?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

Blazor JSInterop has a special JSRuntime that lets me call JS functions from .Net without any marshalling for max performance in a webassembly scenario: [WebAssemblyJSRuntime Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.webassembly.webassemblyjsruntime?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

What is the equivalent in JS for calling a .Net method from JS without marshalling?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no equivalent in JS for calling a .Net method from JS without marshalling. Only JS unmarshalling types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be such functionality at the moment. If anyone sees value in this, add your voice to https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26287

If you use a JS lib from Blazor Webassembly you definitely want that ([10X faster at least](https://www.meziantou.net/optimizing-js-interop-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application.htm)).